# Core plot axis labels not visible outside plot area

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm having some trouble with the axis labels. It seems my custom labels aren't visible outside of the plot area. Looking at the [Design Overview](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/HighLevelDesignOverview) for core plot, the axis labels should be outside of the plot area. Any ideas on how I can make them visible outside the plot area?

The code/image below shows how the labels only show within the plot area. If I change the label offset to a positive number, the labels do not show at all. I'm using Core Plot 0.9 with iOS 5.

Thanks in advance!

```
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
graph = [[theme newGraph] retain];;

CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)self.view;
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

graph.paddingLeft = 40.0;
graph.paddingTop = 40.0;
graph.paddingRight = 40.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 40.0;
graph.masksToBorder = NO;

// ... setup axis
axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

// if this number is negative, the labels show, 
// if it is positive, that is outside the plot area, the labels are hidden.
axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = -20; 

// ... setup labels
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < reportData.rowCount; ++i) {

    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Row %i", i] textStyle:labelStyle];

    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(i);
    label.offset = axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset;
    label.alignment = CPTAlignmentLeft;
    [labels addObject:label];
    [label release];
}
axisSet.yAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:labels];
```

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set some padding on the plot area frame in addition to or instead of the graph itself.

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 20.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 50.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 50.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 50.0;
```

This code is from the axis demo in the Plot Gallery example app.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that option.

Comment: coreplot is such a straight forward thing to use /sarc

Answer (score 7):

I was having exactly the same problem and tried every solution I could find online for this with no success.

Finally I got it to work by turning off the border masking, like this:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
```

Comment: This causes the labels to rendered outside of the bounds of the chart view.  It might be a workable solution if you have left space around the view component, but it's worth being aware of.